# Return the index of the second distinct value in an array?

Tags: ruby

How would I return the index of the second distinct value in an array?
For example, if

```rb
arr = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 12, 12, 3]
```

Then it should return `5` (the first distinct value being 10, so the second distinct value is 15, which is at the 5th index of the array, hence returning 5).

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: The first entry will always be the first unique value. Thus, all you have to do is find the index of the first entry whose value does not match the value of the first value in the array. Look at Array#index for hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
arr.index(arr.uniq[1])
```

See [`Array#index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#method-i-index) and [`Array#uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq).

Answer (score 3):

maybe

```
arr.index {|i| i != arr[0] }
```

Comment: This has the advantage that generally there is no need to examine the entire array. It may be slightly faster to save `arr[0]` to a varaible: `f = arr.first; arr.index {|i| i != f }`.